# How to changet/sort the position of bar by MONTH as a color in plotly express boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, boxplot, plotly-express

friends
Im trying to plot my data to a boxplot.

this is my data

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtFdQ.png)

this is the boxplot graph

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(df_hb, x="QUESTION DETAIL", y="ANSWER", color="MONTH", title="Buy Price", points="outliers", 
             labels={"QUESTION DETAIL" : "Product", "ANSWER" : "Buy Price"})
fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='white',
                  plot_bgcolor='white',
                  autotypenumbers='convert types',
                  legend_traceorder="normal"
)
fig.show()
```

my problem is, i want to sort the position of bar by the month as a color.
i want to move "FEBRUARY" color before "MARCH" color

[graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8fiy.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.box.html), you will see there is an attribute called `category_orders`. You can add the order like that:

```
px.box(......,category_orders={"MONTH": ["FEBRUARY-2022", "MARCH-2022"]})
```